# Jython on Linux: driver [org.postgresql.Driver] not found

Tags: postgresql, jython

I have a Jython script properly running on a Windows 7 machine with PostgreSQL 9. Trying to run the same script on RHE5 Linux with PostgreSQL 8.2 yields the error

```
zxJDBC.DatabaseError: driver [org.postgresql.Driver] not found
```

I tried running the script like so:

```
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/postgresql.jar /path/to/jython /path/to/script.py
```

I also tried setting PYTHONPATH and JYTHONPATH similarly, all yielding the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should mention the script relies on database access to a PostgreSQL database. It uses zxJDBC for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I resolved this. The issue was that I used the wrong driver version. Even though `psql --version` says 8.2 and even though that's the jar version I [downloaded](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html), using the 7.4 version of the driver resolved the issue.